# Do all PHP Exceptions have 'trace', 'message' and 'code' properties?

Tags: php, exception, logging

I have to write a log class that logs the data coming from an exception. To make things simpler, I wanted to know if it is okay to retrieve data inside the 'trace' array and extend this by adding 'message' and 'code' properties of the exception instance in PHP. But I am not sure if all thrown exception in PHP are guaranteed to have at least these three properties ('trace', 'message' and 'code'). Also suggest if there is a better way to log things.

Comment: Since every user exception is extending base class `\Exception`, it will have at least the same functionality. So in general you should base on \Exception class. http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it's better to use code already proven to be good. PHP community widely use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) library check it. If you still want to write your own logger you should stick to [PSR-3 rules](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md)

Answering your question. PHP object thrown must be an instance of the Exception class or a subclass of Exception.

But you if you look at constructor of an Exception

```
  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null);
```

You can throw empty exception.But there will be always code, file, trace and code. Code and Message can be empty.

You can read more about it on http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I agree that it is better to stick with classes already written. But they do not fit my requirements. Either they are too large or miss important features that I am looking for.

Comment: I think monolog fits 99% of needs. I use it in all projects and it can be highly customised also there are plenty of channels, handlers etc.